# Count number of unique symbols for a Buckingham Pi calculation in an expression with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sym

I am trying to write a script that goes through the Buckingham Pi theorem given a list of variables, each having a dimension. The set of dimensions **do not need to be unique** (it can contain repeats) only the same size as the set of variables.

```
clc, clear, close all

syms M L T Theta
dimen = [M,L,T,Theta]
```

- mass - M
- length - L
- time - T
- temperature - Theta

(I can add in other dimensions like electric current later, but for now, I want to get it working with these four).

Here is what I have so far in MatLab.

```
A = L^2;    % maybe an area
V = L/T;    % maybe a velocity
D = M/L^3;  % maybe a density
% This the array of the combinations
param = {A,V,D};
```

I want to count how many of the syms M L T and Theta show up in my cell param.
For example starting at the first entry in the cell array.

```
param{1} = A
L^2
```

At this step, it should count that L has shown up once, and the others 0 times each.

```
param{2} = V
L/T
```

At this step, it counts that L has shown up once, but since it was already counted so I don't want to count it again. It should also count that T has shown up once. So far 1 L, and 1 T.

```
param{3} = D
M/L^3
```

Finally, this count that M has shown up once. So far 1 L, 1 T, and 1 M.
Since there are four possible symbols, I want to end the algorithm with this.

```
j = num; % how many times each of the syms was counted at least once.
```

If a dimension is not counted, that is fine. I am only interested in counting how many times each of the dimensions in the cell array are counted at least once. I will then use these to solve a system of equations to identify dimensionless groups.

I've received some suggestions based on other answers that I am providing below.
[How to extract powers of a symbolic polynomial?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/777072-how-to-extract-powers-of-a-symbolic-polynomial#comment_1646668)

```
present = cellfun(@(expr), ismember(dimen, symvar(expr)), param, 'UniformOutput', false)
counts = sum(vertcat(present{:}), 1)
```

This last suggestions gives this error.

Error using **cellfun**

Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was sym instead.

**Addendum**

Removing the **comma** as suggested in the comments/answer still gives the same error. I am using release 2021b and a mlx file.
[image: Error without comma]

Comment: First remove this comma: `present = cellfun(@(expr)` **,** `ismember(dimen, symvar(expr)), param, 'UniformOutput', false)`. Then I don't have the cellfun error with this script.

Comment: If I remove the comma, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellfun` expects a cell array as its second argument: by introducing a comma between `@(expr)` and `ismember(dimen, symvar(expr))` it's as if you were asking `cellfun` to iterate over the content of `ismember(dimen, symvar(expr))`, which is not what you really want, as that's the body of the anonymous function you are passing to `cellfun` as first argument.

The correct way of using `cellfun` is shown in the following script:

```
clc, clear, close all
syms M L T Theta
dimen = [M,L,T,Theta]
A = L^2;    % maybe an area
V = L/T;    % maybe a velocity
D = M/L^3;  % maybe a density
% This the array of the combinations
param = {A,V,D};

% Counts the appearences of each dimension in each param
% and stores them in a cell array of vectors
present = cellfun(@(expr) ismember(dimen, symvar(expr)), param, 'UniformOutput', false)

% Unpack the cell array of vectors and
% compute the total number of appearences of each dimension
counts = sum(vertcat(present{:}), 1)
```

Comment: If I type `present = cellfun(@(expr) ismember(dimen, symvar(expr)), param, 'UniformOutput', false)` then I still get the same error. I am using version 2021b.

Comment: I am also running this in a mlx file, maybe that's contributing to the issue?

Comment: I just checked whether being in an mlx was the issue, the same error occurs without the comma in a .m file.

Comment: Never mind, I just noticed you changed `param` to a cell array, I should have noticed that. It works perfectly.

Comment: @WnGatRC456 It was already a cell array in the script you posted, actually.

Comment: I noticed that as well, somehow in my older code it was not a cell array. Oh well, it works now. :)