# Identify powers in an algebraic expression for a Buckingham Pi calculation in MatLab

Tags: matlab, exponent, sym

This is a continuation of an earlier question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74894699/count-number-of-unique-symbols-for-a-buckingham-pi-calculation-in-an-expression).

If I create a symbolic expression in MatLab

```
syms L M T
F = M*L/T^2
```

I want to identify the powers of each dimension M, L, or T. In this case, the answer should be

- for M, 1
- for L, 1
- for T, -2

There is a relatively easy way to do this if the expression `F` were a [polynomial](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/777072-how-to-extract-powers-of-a-symbolic-polynomial#comment_1646668) in MatLab employing the `coeffs` function. However, my expression is clearly not a polynomial as far as MatLab is concerned.

In the end, I will be working with at least two parameters so I will put them in a cell array since I anticipate `cellfun` will be useful.

```
V = L/T
param = {F,V};
```

The final output should be a table where the rows correspond to each dimension, L M and T and the columns are for each parameter `F` and `V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
syms L M T
F = M*L/T^2

[C,T] = coeffs(expand(log(F),'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true))
[exp(T).' C.']
```

It returns the table:
[image]